# Wordpress Slider PHP adding Title in thumbnail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slider

I am working with a Wordpress template 'Sahifa' from Tie Labs and their support forum doesn't answer any customization questions so I thought to look for help here. I usually work in HTML/CSS and am relatively new to PHP.

Within the slider there are thumbnail buttons at the bottom that you can click on and we would like for it to call on the same Title information that the caption is pulling. It seems like I'd be looking in the `<li>` and the "slider-thumbs" area from what I can see. I think this is the part of the code where those changes should be made:

```
<?php if( $slider_query != 'custom' ): ?>       
<?php if( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id="ei-slider" class="ei-slider">
    <ul class="ei-slider-large">
    <?php $i= 0;
        while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); $i++; ?>
        <li>
        <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php tie_thumb( $size ); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="ei-title">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php if (tie_get_option( 'slider_caption' )) : ?><h3><?php echo tie_content_limit( get_the_excerpt() , $caption_length ) ?></h3><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </ul>
     <ul class="ei-slider-thumbs">
        <li class="ei-slider-element">Current</li>
    <?php $i= 0;
        while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); $i++; ?>
        <li><a href="#">Slide <?php echo $i; ?><?php tie_thumb( 'tie-medium' ); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </ul><!-- ei-slider-thumbs -->
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to output the post's title, you can simply use the wordpress function **the_title()**

```
<?php echo the_title(); ?>
```

And you can use it anywhere inside the while function, that starts with this:

```
<?php $i= 0;
    while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); $i++; ?>
```

and ends with this:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I tried adding this into that function and wasn't seeing any changes, is there possibly anything else that I should be looking out for?